# How to separate words with digits without changing the order of the input elements in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string of words and digits divided by comma. I need a program that separates words with digits without changing the order of the input elements. The output list (words and digits) should be separated by a pipe ('|').

e.g INPUT SAMPLE:

'8,33,21,0,16,50,37,0,melon,7,apricot,peach,pineapple,17,21,24,13,14,43,41'

OUTPUT SAMPLE:

'melon,apricot,peach,pineapple|8,33,21,0,16,50,37,0,7,17,21,24,13,14,43,41'

Then if the input elements are all digits or words, the pipe ('|') should be omitted.

e.g INPUT SAMPLE

'23,40,2,8'

OUTPUT SAMPLE

'23,40,2,8'

I have a clue of how to do it in C# however, I want a python script and I'm not familiar with python language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code should do the trick.. Basically create two lists which have number and strings in and join them at last..

```
In [21]: num_list = []

In [22]: string_list = []

In [23]: input_string = '8,33,21,0,16,50,37,0,melon,7,apricot,peach,pineapple,17,21,24,13,14,43,41'

In [24]: for elem in input_string.split(','):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         int(elem)
    ...:     except:
    ...:         string_list.append(elem)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         num_list.append(elem)
    ...:

In [25]: string_list
Out[25]: ['melon', 'apricot', 'peach', 'pineapple']

In [26]: num_list
Out[26]:
['8',
 '33',
 '21',
 '0',
 '16',
 '50',
 '37',
 '0',
 '7',
 '17',
 '21',
 '24',
 '13',
 '14',
 '43',
 '41']

In [28]: '|'.join([','.join(string_list), ','.join(num_list)])
Out[28]: 'melon,apricot,peach,pineapple|8,33,21,0,16,50,37,0,7,17,21,24,13,14,43,41'
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the logic would be that you iterate over the input and make two lists, one for the strings and one for the digits. Now, for every string you encounter, you check if the string only has digits, if so, you append it to the digit list, otherwise you append it to a string list. Since python iterates over list elements sequentially, the order will be preserved. At the end, you simply join them together with a pipe.

```py
all_elements = input().split(",")
strings, digits = [], [] 

for element in all_elements:
    digits.append(element) if element.isdigit() else strings.append(element)

print("|".join([",".join(strings) + ",".join(digits)]))
```

Do keep in mind that although you could simply use a `try/except` block to get the job done, Refrain from using try/except blocks if you're going to be running into an exception more than 50% of the time, as a rule of thumb.